# JC Higgins Super Deluxe history?

Tags: sprocket

JC Higgins History Question. After my Mom passed I picked up her JC Higgins Super Deluxe.

I have little history on the bicycle. I have a serial number and Model number from the plate.
Model 505 276 Serial A113 304.

It is a nice bike with a working horn and headlight, looks to be all original aside from the tires, with a rear rack. Any information would be a great help in solving the mysteries surrounding this bike. I know that Mom and her parents were big on the Sears Catalog.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What "mysteries" do you want answers to?  It was manufactured for the Sears, Roebuck Company.  [This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50650/help-decoding-a-j-c-higgins-frame-number-on-a-vintage-cruiser) gives some clues about age, etc.

Comment: Its a nice vintage bike - probably dates from the 60's.  Tyres are a wear item, just like chains and brake pads so that they're not original is good; suggests the bike was maintained.   We don't do Valuations if that's what you seek.

Comment: Interesting location for reflector